# Retrofit.responseBodyConverter does not work to convert errorBody() to custom ResponseWrapper

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, moshi

Trying to convert errorBody() of retrofit error response to ResponseWrapper as follows:

```
retrofit.responseBodyConverter<ResponseWrapper<R>>(Failure::class.java, arrayOf(object : Annotation {}))
                        .convert(response.errorBody())
```

ResponseWrapper is as follows:

```
sealed class ResponseWrapper<R> {

data class Success<R>(val payload: R) : ResponseWrapper<R>()

data class Failure<R>(
        @field:Json(name = "code") val code: Int = INVALID_CODE,
        @field:Json(name = "status") val status: String = "",
        @field:Json(name = "exception") val exception: String = "",
        @field:Json(name = "message") val message: String = "",
        @field:Json(name = "fieldErrors") val fieldErrors: List<FieldError> = emptyList()
) : ResponseWrapper<R>()

class NotFound<R> : ResponseWrapper<R>()

class NoInternet<R> : ResponseWrapper<R>()

data class FieldError(
        @field:Json(name = "field") val field: String,
        @field:Json(name = "message") val message: String,
        @field:Json(name = "rejectValue") val rejectValue: String
) }
```

By doing this with Retrofit/Moshi, error message as follows is created:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Class java.lang.annotation.Annotation.annotationType()"
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.jsonAnnotations(MoshiConverterFactory.java:122)
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(MoshiConverterFactory.java:91)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:330)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
```

What did I wrong here?

Comment: Use just arrayOf for an empty away. You don't need the incomplete single Annotation element.